# app crashing when navigating to diffent activity

Tags: javafx

I'm trying to switch between two anchor panes when I click a button in JavaFX. The first button should navigate to the dashboard pane and the second should navigate to the projects pane.

Can someone help me out

```
@FXML
public JFXButton btndashBoardPane;
public JFXButton btnProjectsPane;

@FXML
public AnchorPane dashBoardPane,projectsPane;

@FXML
public void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event){

    if(event.getSource()==btnProjectsPane){

        projectsPane.setVisible(true);
        projectsPane.toFront();

    }

    if(event.getSource()==btndashBoardPane){

       dashBoardPane.setVisible(true);
       dashBoardPane.toFront();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please include the stacktrace and the error

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add an EventHandler to onAction for both buttons.

```
btndashBoardPane.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            dashBoardPane.setVisible(true);
            projectsPane.setVisible(false);
        }
    });
```

And likewise the same thing vice versa for the btnProjectsPane.

Another approach, but probably less polished would be to have a parent Anchorpane to whose children you add the pane you want to be selected first. The buttons would then clear the children and add their respective pane to the parent Anchorpane.

Comment: if this answer fixed your issue or helped you out, please make sure to [mark it appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)